# If $Φ:E\times Ω\to\mathbb R$ and $Φ(x,\;\cdot\;)$ is measurable for all $x$, then $\left\{ω∈Ω :Φ(E,ω)∩O≠∅\right\}$ is measurable for all open $O$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $(E,d)$ be a compact metric space
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $\Phi:E\times\Omega\to\mathbb R$ such that

  - $\Phi(x,\;\cdot\;)$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable for all $x\in E$
  - $\Phi(\;\cdot\;,\omega)$ is continuous for all $\omega\in\Omega$
- $X(\omega):=\Phi(E,\omega)$ for $\omega\in\Omega$

> How can we show that $$\left\{\omega\in\Omega :X(\omega)\cap O\ne\emptyset\right\}\in\mathcal A\tag1$$ for all open $O\subseteq\mathbb R$?

Comment: The condition on $\omega$ is equivalent to $\Phi(\cdot,\omega)^{-1}(O)\neq\varnothing,$ and by the assumption of continuity, this set is nonempty and open for all $\omega$ in the set of interest... still not seeing how this helps, though.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a countable dense set in E. If $a \in \mathbb R$ then $\{\omega : \phi(x_n,\omega) \leq a,n=1,2,... \}$ is measurable which means  $\{\omega : \phi(x,\omega) \leq a,x \in E \}$ is measurable. Similarly, $\{\omega : \phi(x_n,\omega) \geq b,n=1,2,... \}$ is measurable for each b. Now use the fact that any open set in $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of open intervals.

Comment: Suppose $\emptyset\ne O=\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N}(a_n,b_n)$. Let $A_a:=\{\omega\in\Omega:\Phi(x,\omega)\le a\text{for all }x\in E\}$ and $B_b:=\{\omega\in\Omega:\Phi(x,\omega)\ge b\text{for all }x\in E\}$. We can write $$\left\{\omega\in\Omega :X(\omega)\cap O\ne\emptyset\right\}=\Omega\setminus\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\underbrace{\{\omega\in\Omega:\Phi(x,\omega)\le a_n\text{ or }\Phi(x,\omega)\ge b_n\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb N\}}_{=:\:M_n}\;,$$ but I don't see how you want to express $M_n$ in terms of $A_{a_n}$ and $B_{b_n}$ ... Maybe with some continuity argument?

Comment: Yes, if a continuous function is $\leq a$ at all points of  a dense set then it is $\leq a$ at all points. Similarly, for $\geq b$.

Comment: Sorry, the definition of $M_n$ should be $M_n:=\{\omega\in\Omega:\Phi(x,\omega)\le a_n\text{ or }\Phi(x,\omega)\ge b_n\text{ for all }x\in E\}$. So, if $\omega\in M_n$, why couldn't it be the case that $\Phi(x,\omega)\le a_n$ for all $x\in B_n\subseteq E$ and $(\Phi,x\omega)\ge b_n$ for all $x\in E\setminus B_n$? The dense set $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of points is not involved here ...